# Does such $A,B$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra

true/false test: there're $n\times n$ matrices $A,\ B$ with real entries such that $(I-(AB-BA))^n=0$

I'm cluesless to begin.

Comment: For two numbers commutative property holds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $C = AB - BA$ and assume that $(C - I)^n = 0$.

Then the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $C$ divides $(x - 1)^{n}$. Thus $m(x) = (x-1)^{k}$ for some $1 \leq k \leq n$. This shows that the only eigenvalue of $C$ (considered in $\Bbb{C}$) is $1$, hence the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $(x-1)^{n}$. In particular, $\operatorname{tr}(C) = n > 0$. This contradicts the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(C) = 0$. Therefore no such matrices $A$ and $B$ exist.

Comment: WoW!! Awesome !!

Comment: @SritiMallick, Thank you!